# How to read .log file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I got this .log file. I don't know how to read them as DataFrame

```
 id  |        create_date         
-----+----------------------------
 318 | 2017-05-05 07:03:27.556697
 456 | 2017-07-03 01:50:07.966652
 249 | 2017-05-03 13:57:32.567373
```

Comment: is it really in that format? with those _ascii-art_-ish lines to delimit rows and columns?

Comment: @filippo Yes, true story :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.read_table("data.csv", sep="|", skiprows=[1], header=0, parse_dates=[1]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())

    id                create_date
0  318 2017-05-05 07:03:27.556697
1  456 2017-07-03 01:50:07.966652
2  249 2017-05-03 13:57:32.567373
```

---

### Parameters

- **`sep="|"`**

  Use `|` as column separator
- **`skiprows=[1]`**

  Ignore the second row, which is just decorations and would be the most problematic to parse
- **`header=0`**

  Read column names from the first row
- **`parse_dates=[1]`**

  Convert `create_date` column into pandas `datetime64` format (may be optional)
- **`rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())`**

  Remove extra whitespaces from column names

You may want to add `index_col=0` if you want to make `id` column your index instead of using a sequential one.

Comment: Tks @filipo, It's not actually solve my problem but It gives me clues to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df=pd.read_csv('file_.csv',sep='|')
```

then you can remove `-----+----------------------------` in many ways

1. `df[df[' id  ']!='-----+----------------------------']`
2. `df[~df[' id  '].str.startswith('-')]`
3. `df.drop(0)` # it won't work if your file contains `-----+----------------------------` in any other places for example `footer`
4. `df[df['        create_date         '].notnull()]` # it won't work when your create_date column contains NaN by default.

Output:

```
    id           create_date         
1   318    2017-05-05 07:03:27.556697
2   456    2017-07-03 01:50:07.966652
3   249    2017-05-03 13:57:32.567373
```